# CakePHP redirect function

Tags: php, cakephp

I have the following code that overrides the redirect function in CakePHP:

```
function redirect($url, $status = null, $exit = true)
{
    if(is_array($url))
    {
        $url['?'] = 'continue=true';
    }
    else
    {
        $url.= '?continue=true';
    }
    return parent::redirect($url, $status, $exit);
}
```

However I don't fully understand what the if statement does and what the difference is between the two? I'm hoping to use this function to send a query strings on redirects but need to understand the difference between if `$url` is an array or not.

Answer (score 2):

$url can be either:

> - a Cake-relative URL, like "/products/edit/92" or "/presidents/elect/4"
> - an array specifying any of the following: 'controller', 'action', and/or 'plugin', in addition to named arguments (keyed array
>     elements), and standard URL arguments (indexed array elements)

http://api.cakephp.org/class/router#method-Routerurl

However,

```
$url.= '?continue=true';
```

Won't work if $url is something like "http://www.google.com/search?q=cakephp+url".